# Ion-neutralization processes and its energies

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, ionization-energy

Ionization energies/Electron affinities are well mapped.

I wonder about opposite processes...

I imagine for anion the  necessary energy will be equal to the electron affinity (energy released when the anion was created).

What about cations?

If I had an cation and free electron (both with low kinetic energies) will it automatically recombine?

Or if I had let's say grounded metal surface and near it a cation of some gas, will it do the same (and how would react an anion in this case)?

Thank you for answers. If you could direct me to the proper literature I would be grateful :) (I know it requires QM for any decent description).

Comment: A cation plus electron is always higher energy than the neutral atom. It takes energy to remove the electron, and the cation and electron will recombine if brought together. Likewise an isolated anion is higher energy than the neutral atom plus electron. Ions form only when there is some way to make back the energy required e.g. in NaCl the energy it cost to make the ions is repaid due to the electrostatic attraction between Na$^+$ and Cl$^-$ ions.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I agree with what you said about cations. But are you sure that anion has higher energy then the neutral atom + electron? If that would be the case, would not it make them unstable?

When anion is created the system has higher energy, but I would guess it exclude/emits it away after a while.